# Sugar OS not "on a stick"?

Tags: linux, installation

The [Sugar OS](http://wiki.sugarlabs.org/go/What_is_Sugar?) emphasizes it's "Sugar on a Stick" means of using the OS in a non-permanent way, which is great for most people to try out. However, I have a laptop I would like to install Sugar as the primary (and only) OS for (turning it into a homebuilt [OLPC](http://one.laptop.org/about/software) laptop).

The issue I'm running into is **I can't find a tutorial on how to install Sugar on the PC itself**. It would not need to use the "casper" or other means of being a "persistant live" linux install; it could take advantage of the whole local hard drive.

Since Sugar is a Fedora "spin", I'm *guessing* if I install Fedora on the laptop, I can somehow install the sugar desktop environment and have that replace the default, but I can't find any tutorials on that. Anyone know what that process would be?

(My situation is slightly more complicated by the fact that the laptop being converted is an old Mac iBook, so will need a PPC solution, but a guide on how to do it on a more mainstream chipset would still be useful to get started.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to ( http://wiki.sugarlabs.org/go/Supported_systems#Starch ), 
*Sugar on a Stick Mango Lassi* 0.90.3-1:

> is a Live USB of the Sugar, and one of the primary focuses of
>   Sugar development. **May be installed to HD/USB with liveinst in
>   sugar-terminal**

Comment: I haven't done this, but liveinst may be "fire and forget" with no command line options.

Comment: That Wiki page indicates it's quite outdated, but looking further for "liveinst" info lead me to http://wiki.sugarlabs.org/go/Sugar_Creation_Kit/sck/liveinst. So it looks like the "on a stick" live USB does have a (hidden) means of transferring itself to the hard drive!

Comment: @MidnightLightning So? Any luck installing Sugar **Not** On a Stick? I'm trying here, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

Horatio's answer shows how to take an existing Sugar on a Stick LiveUSB device and transfer that to the computer. I did find one other way to install Sugar as a full, installed OS:

Sugar is available in the Fedora package manager (yum) as a group install (`yum groupinstall "Sugar Desktop Environment"`), so could be added to a full Fedora installation.

The most direct way to go this route (for me with a PPC architecture) is to grab the [PPC Network Install of Fedora 12](http://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/12/Fedora/ppc/iso/Fedora-12-ppc-netinst.iso), and as part of the installation process choose the Sugar package as the Desktop environment rather than Gnome (example of that process for Fedora 16 is on the [Sugar Wiki](http://wiki.sugarlabs.org/go/Sugar_Creation_Kit/sck/netinstall)).